# Set LastGoodBuild in Build Definition

Tags: tfs

I'm working on a custom Build Workflow and need to set the LastGoodBuild at the definition ([MSDN Description of BuildDefinitionDetail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddefinition.aspx)).

Any Ideas how to set the LastGood Build (Not with an update statement in the database :-))

Comment: The latest build that is successful is marked as the LastGoodBuild. There is no api to set this.

Comment: My build is successful and nothing changed!

Comment: I've seen that I have some warnings in the unit-Tests. is it possible that this is my problem?